# Php метод GET

Tags: php, get

Доброго времени.
Сделал простенький сайт, все страницы генерируются через index.php, согласно значению переменной page, переданной через `$_GET['page']`. Далее на одной из страниц, к примеру, `($_GET['page'] = cat_blobe)`, нужно через форму методом GET передать значение input. При нажатии сабмит все слетает, так как через **GET** отправляются только переменные формы, и page больше не существует.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что здесь решением того, чтобы остаться на этой же странице, есть передача текущего значения переменной page, поместив её в скрытый инпут?

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="cat_blobe">
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1. Может, в форме `action="index.php?page=cat_blobe" method="get"`?
2. Из формы хорошо бы POST'ом слать данные, опять же, на action с указанием страницы.

Comment: Просто у меня через GET передается новое значение на котором потом строиться таблица. а вот так action="index.php?page=cat_blobe" method="get" уже пробовал не работает у меня почему то в строке только переменный формы указаны. Наверное я что то делюа не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, в форме action="index.php?page=cat_blobe" method="get"?  - работать не будет - браузер вытащит из index.php?page=cat_blobe только index.php и отправит только значения формы.

Есть много путей решения. Самые простые:

1. Через JS - при нажатии на кнопку отправить сами собираете параметры и делайте редирект на страницу.
2. Аction="index.php?page=cat_blobe" method="post" - данные из формы будут в POST массиве.
3. Как вы и указали - через скрытое поле.
4. Можно в куки положить.

Comment: Спасибо. Все доходчиво и понятно.